# Lista de array com valores iguais

Tags: php, array

Bom tenho uma lista de arrays que trago de uma consulta do banco, dentro dessa consulta tenho produtos iguais, como faço para guardar em outro array todos os elementos que forem iguais?

array:6 [▼
  0 => {#209 ▼

```
+"Cod_Produto": "1002"
+"Produto": "Soja"
```

1 => {#216 ▼

```
+"Cod_Produto": "1002"
+"Produto": "Soja"
```

2 => {#233 ▼

```
+"Cod_Produto": "1003"
+"Produto": "Mamona"
```

3 => {#234 ▼

```
+"Cod_Produto": "1004"
+"Produto": "Oleo de soja"
```

4 => {#235 ▼

```
+"Cod_Produto": "1003"
+"Produto": "Mamona"
```

5 => {#236 ▼

```
+"Cod_Produto": "1003"
+"Produto": "Mamona"
```

Alguma dica? To tentando fazer com que fique assim:

array:1 [▼

0 => {#209 ▼

```
+"Cod_Produto": "1002"
+"Produto": "Soja"
```

1 => {#216 ▼

```
+"Cod_Produto": "1002"
+"Produto": "Soja"
```

array:2 [▼

1 => {#233 ▼

```
+"Cod_Produto": "1003"
+"Produto": "Mamona"
```

2 => {#235 ▼

```
+"Cod_Produto": "1003"
+"Produto": "Mamona"
```

array:3 [▼

1 => {#233 ▼

```
 +"Cod_Produto": "1004"
+"Produto": "Oleo de soja"
```